# Remove base slug in permalinks of hierarchical custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, custom-post-type, permalinks

I have a **hierarchical** Custom Post Type called `project`, registered as follows:

```
register_post_type( 'project',
    array(
        'public'            => true,
        'hierarchical'      => true,
        'rewrite' => array(
            'with_front' => false
        )
    )
);
```

The URLs currently look like this:

- https://example.com/project/hello
- https://example.com/project/hello/world

I would like the URLs to look like this:

- https://example.com/hello
- https://example.com/hello/world

How can I most efficiently accomplish this such that other URLs are not interfered with (e.g. `page`s, blog `post`s, other custom post types)?

All the solutions that are currently out there either cause 404s on other pages on the site or do not work correctly with nested URLs.

Comment: Don't forget to resave Permalinks when adding custom post type or try out other solutions.

Comment: @RST Thanks for the tip, I have been doing that.